# Using template in angular 2 based on window size

Tags: javascript, html, angular

On my template, I have 2 divs. one for table view(laptop) and one for list view(mobile view).

In my .ts file, I want to get the window size so that based on this size, I can choose which div i want to call using ngIf.

In the constructor of the .ts file, I have:

```
let windowSize: number; 
this.windowSize = innerWidth + innerHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    this.windowSize = innerWidth + innerHeight";
});
```

But when i console.log() this.windowSize, I dont get the change when the window is resized. What am i missing?

Comment: You don't need it. HTML5 gives you a basic viewport support. you can use it. So when you resize your window, you get laptop and tablet screen size automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using NgZone. Injected NgZone in my constructor and used it as:

```
 window.onresize = (e) =>
{
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
  });
};
```

By doing this, I was able to check for the change in window in my components. I couldnt use media queries since I had to execute a funtion inside my .ts file based on window size change.

Answer (score 2):

This can be set with simple css:

```
 @media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px) {
    .div1 {
      display: none;
    }

 @media (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    .div2 {
      display: none;
    }
```